# Altering a table on a different server through a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing some dynamic SQL (I'm fairly new to it) and am trying to automate the altering of multiple tables which may exist on different instances of SQL Server 2008.  My servers are linked and I know which server each of the tables exists on, however when I try to run the query below, I get "Cannot find object...because it does not exist or you do not have persmissions"

Query:

```
Alter Table [Server10].[Database2].[dbo].[documents] Add NewField int
```

If I connect to the server in SSMS and drop the server name (Server10) it works.

Any suggests on how to create this query.  Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting a "double hop"?  [http://lextonr.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/double-hop-linked-servers/]

Comment: I do not believe so because I can run a select on that table using the same server path

Comment: For the linked server properties, what are the security settings?  I usually don't use login mappings.  Connections will "Be made using the login's current securit context".  I connect with Windows Authentication and I'm a sysadmin on both servers, so I wouldn't have any restrictions.

Comment: I'm an admin through Windows Authentication.  If I connect to that server directly through SSMS I can create the new field or drop it so I don't think it's my user rights.

Comment: It's all depicted by the security settings of the linked server. You may be an admin in the context of your connection to ServerA, but you may not be for the context of the linked server connection to ServerB.  For instance, the linked server may be using impersonation, or a security context specific to ServerB.

Comment: 2 questions:  How would I check that? and Is the structure of the query ok?

Comment: If I switch to Server10, the query would still not work.  I would have to drop the [Server10] part of the query for it to work.  I think I need some kind of USE command except at the Server level instead of just the database level.

Comment: From SSMS, log into ServerA.  In the object explorer, expand Server Objects, expand Linked Servers.  Find your linked server ("Server10", right?), right-click it and select Properties.  In the Properties window, click "Security" to see how connections to Server10 are made.

The query should be fine since it runs when you are connected directly to Server10.

Comment: DMason. Appreciate the help.  I'm talking to admin about those permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that alter table on a linked server is not supported. You could do something like this:

EXECUTE [Server10].[Database2].[dbo].sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE [documents] Add NewField int'

Comment: Tnanks.  I think that gets me a step closer.  I get that the server is not configured for RPC.  I'll take to admin about that.  Thanks

Comment: Goog, admin should be to help you. I think you must have enabled RPC OUT - take a look at the linked server properties.

There might also be a need to apply the latest service packs (and restart the sql server engine).